# Runtime Exception startPreview failed inside callback onPictureTaken

Tags: android, android-camera, runtimeexception

I have created one camera application using Android camera api. I am taking picture using mCamera.takePicture(mShutterCallback, null, mPicture) method and getting callback inside public void onPictureTaken(final byte[] data, Camera camera) {} where I am calling mCamera.startPreview(); This code is working good for many photos but after some times I am getting the Runtime exception startPreview failed. I was looking into logs and found following log points before the crash:-

```
04-05 15:55:09.116 814-7001/? E/Camera3-Device: Camera 0: getStreamInfo: Device has encountered a serious error
04-05 15:55:09.116 814-7001/? E/Camera2-StreamingProcessor: updatePreviewStream: Camera 0: Error querying preview stream info: Function not implemented (-38)
04-05 15:55:09.116 814-7001/? E/Camera2Client: startPreviewL: Camera 0: Unable to update preview stream: Function not implemented (-38)
04-05 15:55:10.118 814-7001/? E/Camera3-Device: Camera 0: getStreamInfo: Device has encountered a serious error
04-05 15:55:10.118 814-7001/? E/Camera2-StreamingProcessor: updatePreviewStream: Camera 0: Error querying preview stream info: Function not implemented (-38)
04-05 15:55:10.119 814-7001/? E/Camera2Client: startPreviewL: Camera 0: Unable to update preview stream: Function not implemented (-38)
04-05 15:55:10.119 2907-2907/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM


                                                 --------- beginning of crash
04-05 15:55:10.120 2907-2907/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: com.sample.project, PID: 2907
                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: startPreview failed
                                                     at android.hardware.Camera.startPreview(Native Method)
                                                     at com.sample.project.screen$18.run(Screen.java:817)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

I am getting this issue in google Pixel phone running oreo 8.0. Please provided me some suggestion to proceed.

Comment: You are running into a low-level error within the camera HAL, which ideally can't happen no matter what settings you use; to help sort out how to avoid the issue, what are you using for Camera.Parameters?

Comment: @EddyTalvala Thanks for the reply. I am setting some camera parameters like picture size, preview size, set focus mode, setZoom, setRotation, set metering areas. Do you think this parameters can cause the issue?

Comment: Certainly possible; a bug could be triggered by any of those parameters, or some combination of multiple parameters. It's very hard to say which, so you basically just have to try changing values to see if the crash goes away.  A certain combination of picture and preview size is one frequent problem; sometimes having too big and too small size in combination breaks, or different aspect ratios.

Answer (score 0):

The Android Camera API works on thousands of different device models from dozens of manufacturers. Even though they try hard, each implementation has its own glitches. If we, software developers, are lucky enough, we come across these glitches when our apps are installed *en masse*.

One rule is that any camera call may fire a RuntimeException, in a scenario that succeeds for 99% of devices and users, with no fault on our side. Therefore, if you plan wide device support, you should always catch this exception, and define the fallbacks for each failing call. Quite often, trying to do exactly same for the second time, simply succeeds.

Another rule is that both the old deprecated Camera API and the new camera2 API may be less stable when they work in compatibility mode. Your question suggests that the device has native camera2 support, but you use the old API. You may find that some glitches will be gone, or easier to handle, if you rewrite your code to use camera2 API directly. But don't delete the deprecated API code: you can find that on devices with

```
CameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL) == CameraCharacteristics.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_LEGACY)
```

the old code will be more reliable.

Comment: Alex Cohn Thanks for reply in details. I am using google pixel and  I have to support my app for this device only. I already tried to catch exception and tried it again after 2 sec but it keeps getting failure. I was doing upload of images in background and shooting pictures using camera at a same time. Once I removed my code of uploading image this issue is not coming. Don't know how they are conflicting. Currently I am catching the exception and displaying dialog to retry or exit from activity. Do you think we can handle this issue in any other way?

Comment: That's an unusual race condition. But maybe the upload thread blocks somehow the thread that is used by camera API, and some calls there time out. Try to set thread priority for uploader lower.